# Testcafe newline in contenteditable

Tags: html, automated-tests, contenteditable, keyboard-events, testcafe

In Testcafe you cannot trigger a new line in a contenteditable with .pressKey('enter'). Is there a possible solution to taht problem?

I have tried to trigger a keyboardevent through a clientFunction but it didnt work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

  <h1>Template</h1>
  
  <div id="123" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 200px; width:200px;" contenteditable="true">This is a blank template for a web page.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Testcafe:

```
test('memo', async t => {



    await t
    .click(Selector('#123'))

    await t.eval(() =>{
         var el = document.getElementById('123')
         var evt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {altKey:false,
       bubbles: true,
       cancelBubble: false, 
       cancelable: true,
       charCode: 0,
       code: "Enter",
       composed: true,
       ctrlKey: false,
       currentTarget: null,
       defaultPrevented: true,
       detail: 0,
       eventPhase: 0,
       isComposing: false,
       isTrusted: true,
       key: "Enter",
       keyCode: 13,
       location: 0,
       metaKey: false,
       repeat: false,
       returnValue: false,
       shiftKey: false,
       type: "keydown",
       which: 13,
       view: window
       })

    el.dispatchEvent(evt);

        
    // });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add a new line to the contenteditable element using TestCafe API.
The 'pressKey("enter")' action does not work with `contenteditable` elements according to the following article:
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402693/reference/test-api/testcontroller/presskey.

However, I think we need to support the usage scenario to type multiline text using the `typeText` function.

Please create a separate issue in the TestCafe repository using the following template: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml.